# inverse system of groups over a direct product of two posets

Tags: category-theory, finite-groups

I'm interested in a problem involving finite groups, where I've discovered that inverse systems and their limits are useful for describing certain subgroups. I'm especially interested in the inverse system of finite groups over a finite poset because its limit is also finite.

My question is as follows: Consider two finite posets, $I$ and $J$, and let $G_{(i,j)}$ be a finite group for every pair $(i,j)$ in $I\times J$. We have an inverse system denoted by $((G_{(i,j)})_{(i,j)\in I\times J}, (f_{(i_1,j_1)(i_2,j_2)})_{(i_1,j_1)\le (i_2,j_2)\in I\times J})$.
I would like to know if the following formula holds true:
$$\lim_{i\in I}\lim_{j\in J}G_{(i,j)}\cong\lim_{(i,j)\in I\times J}G_{(i,j)}\cong \lim_{j\in J}\lim_{i\in I}G_{(i,j)}$$

*@Käsekuchen gave a wonderful comment on this question.*

I'm not very familiar with category theory. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide me with a reference for above questions.

Comment: If I understand correcty this is a standard result in category. See [this nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limits+commute+with+limits) for a precise statement and a reference. If you are new to category theory you  might not like the proof given in the nlab so maybe you might consult [this blog article](https://blog.thjread.com/posts/2020-04-15-limits-commute.html) I just found. The author works out a proof using the universal property of the limit which you might be more familiar with.

Comment: @Käsekuchen Thank you! That's very helpful.

Comment: I am glad. Feel free to ask if you have any troubles.