# What conditions can ensure the inverse limits of finite groups over finite posets preserve the exactness?

Tags: category-theory, finite-groups, order-theory

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729631/inverse-system-of-groups-over-a-direct-product-of-two-posets) about the commutativity of inverse limits before. Since I am interested in using inverse system to describe certain subgroups of a finite group, I always assume the groups and posets are finite.

Having reading some material on inverse systems, a new question about exactness arise in my mind. Generally, the exactness of surjective inverse systems over a finite poset is not preserved by their limits. I am curious about **the specific conditions, except being "directed," under which the limits of surjective inverse systems can preserve exactness**. Note that a directed finite poset has unique maximal elements, which makes the case trivial. In other words, being "directed" is too strong.

For the condition, I have an idea on it. Let $I$ be a poset satisfying for any $x,y\in I$,
$$\exists z\in I, z\ge x,z\ge y\iff x\ge y \mbox{ or }y\ge x.$$
​I believe that limits of surjective systems over $I$ preserve exactness. In summary, my question is as follows:

1. Is this true that such an $I$ can ensure the preservation of exactness? If so, does this $I$ or this condition have a name?
2. Are there any other conditions under which the limits of surjective system preserve the exactness?

Comment: See:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mittag-Leffler+condition

Comment: @Randall Thank you for your comments! I tried to find some conditions before and the Mittag-Leffler condition is where I started. But this condition doesn't apply here. In fact, a surjective inverse system always enjoys the Mittag-Leffler condition and we can construct a counter-example for surjective inverse limit. If I understand correctly, Mittag-Leffler condition also need the poset is directed to ensure the exactness but in my question, I hope to find an alternative condition on posets.